fstab entry variable inside or outside function
So, I am working on a script that mounts smb shares.
I have this function:
def fstab_entry(samba_ip, sharename, mountpoint, credentials):
    # Build mount entry line for fstab
    entry = f"//{samba_ip}/{sharename} {mountpoint} cifs rw,x-systemd.automount,credentials={credentials},uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0\n"
    existing_entry = f"//{samba_ip}/{sharename}"

    try:
        # Read existing entries from fstab
        with open("/etc/fstab", "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()

        # Check if the entry already exists
        if any(line.strip() == existing_entry for line in lines):
            print(
                f"A line in /etc/fstab for {existing_entry} already exists. New entry not added."
            )
        else:
            # Append the new entry to fstab
            with open("/etc/fstab", "a") as f:
                f.write(entry)
                print(f"New entry on /etc/fstab for {existing_entry} added.")

            # Print the updated contents of fstab
            print("Updated /etc/fstab:")
            with open("/etc/fstab", "r") as f:
                print(f.read())
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error at adding the entry on /etc/fstab: {e}")

But then I realize it is possible that i need the variable entry in other function such as error_cleanup
def error_cleanup(credentials_path, ):
    if os.path.exists():
# in construction...

Should I define this variable with the other ones?:
def main():
    ############### Configurable Variables ###################################
    mnt_folder = input("Local folder address:")
    samba_server_ip = input("IP address Samba Server:")
    share_name = input("Share Name: ")
    samba_user = input("Samba username: ")
    samba_pass = getpass("Samba password: ")
    samba_domain = input("Domain(optional): ")
    samba_path_credentials = "/etc/samba/credentials"
    credentials_filename = samba_server_ip + "_credentials"
    credentials_filepath = samba_path_credentials + "/" + credentials_filename
# more code...

You can comment whatever you want in order to optimize the code.

Seems like a decent library routine.
default kwarg
def fstab_entry( ..., credentials):
    ...
    entry = f"//{samba_ip}/{sharename} {mountpoint} cifs rw,x-systemd.automount,credentials={credentials},uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0\n"

Consider tacking on keyword args like
def ..., credentials, options="x-systemd.automount,", uid=1000, gid=None):
    ...
    gid = gid or uid
    entry = f"{existing_entry} {mountpoint} cifs rw,{options}credentials={credentials},uid={uid},gid={gid} ...

(I know, supporting gid == 0 would require a fancier check.)
prefix match
        if any(line.strip() == existing_entry for line in lines):

I don't understand that line.
Are you sure it ever triggers?
I anticipate that non-comment lines in
fstab
shall have six fields.
swallowed exception
Do we even need this?
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error at adding the entry on /etc/fstab: {e}")

Maybe your requirements document wrote down
that outputting that particular diagnostic text is a Requirement.
Cool.
We should still re-raise,
to let caller know that all bets are off
and we were unable to make good on our
promise.
use pathlib
I heard you say
def error_cleanup(credentials_path: str) -> None:
    if os.path.exists(credentials_path):
        ...

Prefer this:
def error_cleanup(credentials: Path) -> None:
    if credentials.exists():
        ...

object attributes

Should I define this variable with the other ones?

Rather than create lots of module-level globals,
consider defining a class which can then use e.g.
self.credentials_filepath = samba_credentials_folder / credentials_filename
